# Add a Phonegap plugin to the Phonegap plugins repository on Github

Tags: cordova, github, phonegap-plugins

I have a Phonegap / Cordova plugin in [my own GitHub repository](https://github.com/remcob00/cordova-phonegap_youtube_player_api_android) and I would like to add this plugin to the Phonegap plugins repository on GitHub at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins. How can I achieve this?

**Edit**

The Phonegap Plugins repository says:

> We don’t want to “clutter” this repo with code anymore. Authors should maintain the code in their own repos and just put a pointer in a README.md in this repo.

But what do they mean with?

> just put a pointer in a README.md in this repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a plugin in the way described in Nick Roth's answer, fork the [phonegap/phonegap-plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) repo to your GitHub account. Add a folder for your plugin in your fork under the appropriate platform (iOS, Android, etc) that contains a README.md

In the README.md include a short description of your plugin and any other info that might help someone know if it's the right plugin for them along with a link to the plugin in your GitHub account.

Examples:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ActionSheet
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/VolumeSlider

Then commit that and send a pull request to the `phonegap/phonegap-plugins` repo and we will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at README for that repo it doesn't look like they are accepting more plugins to it.

`We don’t want to “clutter” this repo with code anymore. Authors should maintain the code in their own repos and just put a pointer in a README.md in this repo.`

Comment: What do they mean with: "and just put a pointer in a README.md in this repo."?

Comment: I don't use GitHub that much so I don't know exactly what they mean by that.

Comment: @RemcoBeugels It means add a link in the readme.md to you repository.